# <script> tag only works on page refresh (Single Page Application)

Tags: javascript, html, express, single-page-application

I'm building a single-page application using plain Javascript + express-JS. I have two views linked to two anchor links so that I can toggle between the views. The problem is, one of the views (the default view) displays a d3 chart, and it only displays it when the site initially loads or on page refresh. If I just click on its own anchor link, theoretically it should do nothing and still display the chart but the chart vanishes but all the other html elements corresponding to that view stay. I'm making sure my script tag for that file is getting loaded into the base html file after all of my content is being loaded in, but still the issue persists. Can someone point out what's going wrong here?.

```
var tag = document.createElement("script");

function scriptLoad() {
    tag.src = "static/js/d3chart.js";
    tag.id = "d3chart"
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(tag);
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (e.target.matches("[data-link]")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            navigateTo(e.target.href);
        }
        scriptLoad();
    });
    router();
});
```

HTML anchor links in base html file

```
<a href="/" data-link>View 1</a>
<a href="/view2" data-link>View 2</a>
```

Whole Code

```
import view1 from "./views/view1.js"
import view2 from "./views/view2.js"

const pathToRegex = path => new RegExp("^" + path.replace(/\//g, "\\/").replace(/:\w+/g, "(.+)") + "$");

const getParams = match => {
    const values = match.result.slice(1);
    const keys = Array.from(match.route.path.matchAll(/:(\w+)/g)).map(result => result[1]);

    return Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, i) => {
        return [key, values[i]];
    }));
};

const navigateTo = url => {
    history.pushState(null, null, url);
    router();
};

const router = async () => {
    const routes = [
        { path: "/", view: view1 },
        { path: "/view2", view: view2 }
    ];

    // Test each route for potential match
    const potentialMatches = routes.map(route => {
        return {
            route: route,
            result: location.pathname.match(pathToRegex(route.path))
        };
    });

    let match = potentialMatches.find(potentialMatch => potentialMatch.result !== null);

    if (!match) {
        match = {
            route: routes[0],
            result: [location.pathname]
        };
    }

    const view = new match.route.view(getParams(match));

    document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = await view.getHtml();

};

window.addEventListener("popstate", router);

var tag = document.createElement("script");

function scriptLoad () {
    tag.src = "static/js/d3chart.js";
    tag.id = "d3chart"
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(tag);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (e.target.matches("[data-link]")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            navigateTo(e.target.href);
        }
        scriptLoad();
    });
    router();
});
```

view1.js file - the default view on start (chart view)

```
import AbstracView from "./AbstractView.js"

export default class extends AbstracView {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.setTitle("D3 Chart - View1");
    }
   
    async getHtml() {
        return `
            <h1>D3 Chart</h1>
            <div class="chart-area"></div>
        `;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are executing `scriptLoad()` function inside the click listener, it should be done outside, otherwise, on every click you are reloading the same file, which seems to be your issue.

Comment: I put it outside and it didn't work. I'm also using the History API, is that somehow leading to this? Also, initially, when I just had the script tag in the base html file, the chart didn't even load on start or refresh. Once I made sure the script tag got inserted after the content was loaded, the chart showed up, but it disappears when I click on its own anchor link

Comment: I don't think it is related to the History API, but it might depend on what you are doing in the `navigateTo` function. Just to be sure, you moved the `scriptLoad` outside the `click` listener, but you kept it inside the `DOMContentLoaded` listener, correct? If so, show us the rest of your code, like the template and the content of the `navigateTo` function.

Comment: I have updated my question with the rest of the code. Let me know if you need to take a look at anything else. And yes, I called the `scriptLoad();` function within the `DOMContentLoaded` listener but outside the `click` listener. I called it right above the `router();` function call.

Comment: Is there any reason for the `script` not being loaded on the HTML file directly?

Comment: The chart is supposed to render into a div (chart-area). I think the script tag runs before the div itself gets added into the base html file, and so the d3 code from the script tag is not able to find it's render location, hence the chart doesn't show up. Initially I had the script tag placed directly in the base html, but as I said, the chart doesn't appear.

Comment: Also, if you meant, why not paste the whole d3 code inside of the html, I did that as well but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so a person on Reddit helped me resolve the issue, and essentially what I had to do was create a method inside of the class in the view1.js file and place my d3 code inside of that method, like so

```
import AbstracView from "./AbstractView.js"

export default class extends AbstracView {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.setTitle("D3 Chart - View1");
    }

    loadChart() {
        // My D3 code here
    }
   
    async getHtml() {
        return `
            <h1>D3 Chart</h1>
            <div class="chart-area"></div>
        `;
    }
}
```

Later, I just had to call it, like so in my router file

```
const view = new match.route.view(getParams(match));

document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = await view.getHtml();

view.loadChart?.(); // runs the method after the HTML corresponding to the view has been added to the base HTML.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your function inline or add new event listener on click "a" html tag.

```html
<a onclick="scriptLoad()" href="/" data-link>View 1</a>
<a onclick="scriptLoad()" href="/view2" data-link>View 2</a>
```

Comment: Care to explain your answer? This doesn't really follow for me.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. I do have an event listener, and if I call the `scriptLoad();` inside of the IF statement, that you see in my code, the chart doesn't load on start, but it loads when I click on the anchor tag, but only once. If I do it again, it doesn't. To get it to work again, I need to refresh the page, click on the anchor tag, and then the chart shows up again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, the file `d3chart.js` will run the code to create the chart and apply it to a div with the class name `chart-area`. The quick and dirty way to have your code working, would be doing the following:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (e.target.matches("[data-link]")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            navigateTo(e.target.href);
        }
        // scriptLoad(); <- remove this
    });
    router();
});
```

**view1.js**

```js
import AbstracView from "./AbstractView.js"

export default class extends AbstracView {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.setTitle("D3 Chart - View1");
    }
   
    async getHtml() {
        return `
            <h1>D3 Chart</h1>
            <div class="chart-area"></div>
            <script id="d3chart" src="static/js/d3chart.js"></script>
        `;
    }
}
```

This would solve your initial problem but would create a new one, as you might already figured out, it makes an HTTP request every time you load that view! That might be what you want, but if not, you would need to change the structure of your code a bit. The code of the file `d3chart.js` would need to expose a `loadChart` function (or whatever you want to call it) and then you would load that script once and call the `loadChart` function whenever the view needs to be updated.

**d3chart.js**

```js
function loadChart() {
  // Your code to create the chart and apply it to the an element.
}
```

**Template**

```html
<script id="d3chart" src="static/js/d3chart.js"></script>

<a href="/" data-link>View 1</a>
<a href="/view2" data-link>View 2</a>

<div id="app"></div>
```

**view1.js**

```js
import AbstracView from "./AbstractView.js"

export default class extends AbstracView {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.setTitle("D3 Chart - View1");
    }
   
    async getHtml() {
        return `
            <h1>D3 Chart</h1>
            <div class="chart-area"></div>
            <script>loadChart();</script>
        `;
    }
}
```

Comment: The chart disappears completely in both the solutions you mentioned. In your second solution, you asked me to place `loadChart();` inside `getHtml()` under the `chart-area` div, I checked the console and the d3 script wasn't loading, so instead I moved the `constructor()` to the bottom, below `getHtml();` and called `loadChart();` inside of it. The script loaded but chart doesn't appear. I'll keep trying though, with your solutions, making few changes here and there to see if I can rectify the issue.

Comment: Did you also change the script and the template code to match the code in my solution? Don't know if you saw, but I added the loading of the script in the template.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it and I added it.

Comment: Ok, I'm out of ideas then. I will take a closer look at home. Let us know if you find it out in the meanwhile :)

Comment: Sure man, thank you so much for your time. I'll update the question and let you know, if I figure it out.